# Alter column length without check constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change my column length with this script:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn VARCHAR (20)
```

But when I run the above query, it shows the following error:

> The object 'FK_field' is dependent on column 'mycolumn'

I had used

```
ALTER TABLE mytable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_field
```

but it's still not working.

So how to change length of column without checking a constraint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the column in question is being referenced by a FK constraint, you will have to drop the constraint first. You will also need to change the length of the referencing column as well and then recreate the FK

Answer (score 2):

Drop the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_field]
```

Change length of the column:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn VARCHAR (20)
```

Create the constraint again:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK_field) 
    REFERENCES ....
```

Comment: Not really complete. The referencing column length/datatype also needs to change to match the referred column